# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method (How to use relative path with DOS commands in Groovy?)

Tags: groovy, dos

I'm trying to run a simple DOS command (pushed with relative path) in Groovy. "pfxFileFolde" is defined at test suite level as "${projector}/testfolder".

```
def pfxFileFolder = context.expand('${#TestCase#pfxFileFolder}')
String command = "cmd /c pushd "pfxFileFolder"";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I got error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script70.cmd /c pushd () is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/my/relative/path/testfolder] error at line: 37

I'm pretty new to JAVA, Groovy. How can I use Java def (relative path) with DOS commands in Groovy?

The below command works, so pfxFileFolder is correct.
    log.info pfxFileFolder

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is wrong.  Either use `'` or quote your `"` with `\"`:

```
String command = 'cmd /c pushd "pfxFileFolder"';
```

Already the syntax highlighting on here on SO makes this obvious.